# Manipulating big Numpy python images with parallelisation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, parallel-processing, dask

I have a complexe issue. I have 50 images. Each image is corresponding to a date and have a shape of (10,5490,5490). What I want to do is to extract for each position x,y not masked, the values of the ten channels and for each date. In addition, I am trying to interpolate the series to smooth the temporal profiles.
I have a Python code working to extract this information and save each time series as a CSV file (1 csv file = one time series = 1 pixel for the 10 channels).

My issue is regarding the size of my input arrays (10,5490,5490). When I try to load the 50 images as numpy Array, I have a memory error.

So I divided my input images as chunks with Dask, And I am able to load the 50 images and stack them.

I am really novice for paralleisation processing, but now, I am trying to adapt the part of code which iterates over rows and columns to extract, interpolate and save temporal profiles. I have no idea how to adapt this part of code using the daks array I created before in order to parallelise the time series extraction. Indeed, with my for loops, it take a very very long time to extract all pixels time series.

I joined my code to have an idea of my process:

```
    # Date of images
    date_graph1 = [datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 6, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 6, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 18, 0, 0)]
    
    # My binary mask to extract time series only for pixels where the mask == 1
    image_mask = './mask_image.tiff'
    ds_mask =gdal.Open(image_mask)
    mask = np.array(ds_mask.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())

    # Format dates
    dates_arr=[]
    for date in date_graph1:
        dates_arr.append(pd.Timestamp(date))
    dates_arr = np.array(dates_arr)


    # Formatting of the images as arrays
    # liste_merged is the list of image files (GeoTiff)
    # liste_cld is the list of image cloud mask files (GeoTiff)
    imageBands=[]
    for image,cld in zip(liste_merged,liste_cld):
        ds = gdal.Open(image)
        ds_cld = gdal.Open(cld)

        # With chunks
        myarrayCloud = da.from_array(ds_cld.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(),chunks=(1000,1000))
        myarray = da.from_array(ds.ReadAsArray(), chunks=(1,1000,1000))
        
        # The version without chunks (give a momory error when I try to load all images)
        #yarrayCloud = ds_cld.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
        #myarray = ds.ReadAsArray()

        # Set no data when cloud mask is 1 and when pixel value are < 0 (some pixels have wrong negative values)
        myarray2 = np.where(np.logical_and(myarrayCloud==0,myarray>=0),myarray,np.nan)

        # Add to the list the (10,5490,5490) array for all dates
        imageBands.append(myarray2)

      
    imageBands = da.stack(imageBands, axis=0)
    print(imageBands)
    print('SHAPE',imageBands.shape)
    #This prints : "SHAPE (50, 10, 5490, 5490)"

    

    ########
    # This is a second part of code to adapt with the dask Arrays. In my original version
    # working with a subset of image but not working on whole images and all dates.
    # In my original version imageBands is not a daks array but just a list containing the 50 arrays
    # of size (10, 5490, 5490) 
    # I have no idea how to begin to adapt this part

    i=0
    # Iteration over row and columns
    for x in tqdm(range(0,5490)):
        for y in range(0,5490):
            #Apply the mask
            if mask[x,y] == 1:
                print ("Pixel to process")
                listeBand=[]
                # Go trhough the different images
                for dateIm in imageBands:
                    listeValue=[]
                    # Go trhough the dimensions of image (10 channel)
                    for band in dateIm:
                        listeValue.append(band[x,y])
                    listeBand.append(listeValue)


                # Create the dataframe with the pixel value for each channel and each date
                df=pd.DataFrame({"B2":[item[0] for item in listeBand],
                    "B3":[item[1] for item in listeBand],
                    "B4":[item[2] for item in listeBand],
                    "B5":[item[3] for item in listeBand],
                    "B6":[item[4] for item in listeBand],
                    "B7":[item[5] for item in listeBand],
                    "B8":[item[6] for item in listeBand],
                    "B8A":[item[7] for item in listeBand],
                    "B11":[item[8] for item in listeBand],
                    "B12":[item[9] for item in listeBand]},index =dates_arr)

                # Interpolation and index value every 5 days
                dset = df.reindex(
                            pd.date_range(start=datetime.datetime(df.index.min().year,1,1),
                                            end=datetime.datetime(df.index.min().year,12,31),
                                            freq='5D'),
                            method='ffill').interpolate(method='time')#rolling("10D").sum()


                # Remove values < 0
                dset[dset < 0] = 0

                # Transpose
                dset = dset.transpose()

                # Row names
                dset['channels']='B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11','B12'
                cols = list(dset.columns)
                cols = [cols[-1]] + cols[:-1]
                dset = dset[cols]

                # Export to CSV
                dset.to_csv('/data/tests/CSV/file%s.csv'%i, sep=',',index=False)
                print ("pixel n°: %s \n"%i)

            i+=1
```

Concerning the output I am expecting one csv file by processed pixel (this may not be the best solution either). CSV files contains the time series for each band: bands in row and dates in column –

Here is a [image: screenshot] of my expected output

Here is a [Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OA5GiNgiVH8VUP0S5tyOYkPnm9SYA3oK/view) to access to one image

Many thanks in advance for any help or any direction to take.

Comment: Surely each pixel is entirely independent of the pixel above/below and left/right of it and all the other bands? So, rather than holding 50days*10bands*5490rows*5490cols in memory at once, you could, for example, process a single row of pixels of one band at a time requiring just 50days*1band*5490cols, i.e 54,900x less RAM.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: In addition to rpanai's comments, could you please be clearer about how many output files you expect, and what is in each? Also, can you share an image please - you'll probably have to use Dropbox or Google Drive for TIFFs. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for answer. 
 Yes it is a possibility. I already made a test using one band at a time. It is working, but my problem is the processing time because I need to iteterate overs each pixel and each band. With the division in chunks, I would like to generate the same process with parallisation to reduce the processing time. To give you an idea, it take more or less 12h to process one bande.

Comment: @rpanai thanks for you answer. Sorry is my issue is not well formulated. I tried to explain the more clearer as possible. I will try to write a simpler version of the code as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick attempt at this - though I have never used GeoTIFF, GDAL or Rasterio before - so there may be better ways.

For absolute simplicity I made 50 copies of your 1 day of data, called `day0.tif`, `day1.tif` etc. I also hard-coded the height and width of your images.

It works by processing one band at a time, and then in each band, I stack 50 days' of data into chunks, 32 rows high and the full width of your image. Then I run a 1D convolution of length 5 along the axis of the days, i.e. the last axis.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import rasterio
from rasterio.windows import Window
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import convolve1d

def GetData(band, day, row, nRows):
   # https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html#windowrw
   with rasterio.open(f'day{day}.tif') as src:
      d = src.read(band,window=Window(0, row, 5490, nRows))
   # Note that you may get fewer rows than expected on the last tile
   return d

# Hard-coded for simplicity
rows, cols = 5490, 5490
rowsPer    = 32          # Number of rows we process at a time
days       = 50

print(f'pid: {os.getpid()} (for finding in "top")')

# Smoothing kernel - taking a rolling mean of N samples
kernel = np.ones(5)
kernel /= kernel.sum()
print(f'Kernel: {kernel}')

for band in range(1,11):
   print(f'DEBUG: Processing band {band}')
   for row in range(0,rows,rowsPer):
      #print(f'DEBUG: Processing row {row}')
      stackOfDays = np.zeros((rowsPer,cols,days),np.uint16)
      for day in range(0,days):
          d = GetData(band, day, row, rowsPer)
          # Stack into stackOfDays
          stackOfDays[:d.shape[0],:,day] = d
      # Convolve along last axis, i.e. along days axis
      smoothed = convolve1d(stackOfDays, kernel, mode='nearest', axis=-1)
```

It runs the entire dataset of 10 bands over 50 days of data in 900 seconds on my MacBookPro. I didn't save any output results as it is unclear what you want exactly - though writing a few TIFFs at the end of each band would hardly change the time at all.

I guess you could multi-process and do one band per process if 900 seconds is too long. Of course, you can mess around with all my sizes and see if it can better suit your machine.

You can monitor the process as it runs to see how much RAM it uses like this, on **macOS** at least - or you can use `top` or `htop`:

```
/usr/bin/time -l script.py
```

Comment: The convolution kernel is a Numpy array of 5 elements, each equal to 1/5 and that is applied to every pixel in the 32x5490 array of data along the *days* axis. So the result will be that the pixel for each day will become the average of the two previous days, the current day and the two following days - i.e. averaged across 5 days. You could make it 3 days or 7 days by just changing the length of the kernel. Try experimenting with that and I'll work on the other part later as I am busy today.

Comment: Many thanks for your interesseting answer, indeed it is faster and shorter in comparison to my code.
If I well understant the data are smoothed along the time axis with the convolution ?
"smoothed" are arrays with shape (32, 5490, 50), so 32 rows in the 5490 columns and 50 dates, then how to extract the csv for each pixel along time (individual time series). I think the problem of processing time is more related to this question, beacause processing pixel by pixel is very time consuming.

Comment: Sorry fo rmy lack of experience on SO, I made some edits to my comment, and I also edited my question with an image (on Google Drive) and a screenshot of the output as you asked. 
Many thanks for your help it is really appreciated.

Comment: You should find you can save a CSV quite fast with `numpy.savetxt()` see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already save the CSV files in my original script. My issue is concerning the processing time because I have to iterate over each pixel. I would like to create chunks (as I made in with Dask) and then process them in parallel.